# "One" vs using " Each one"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns

I know that the word "one" refers to people in general.So what is the difference between phrase 1 and 2.

1-Each one should look after oneself in these circumstances.

2-One should look after oneself in these circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Take your second example first.

It uses the indefinite pronoun **one** to mean a person, any person. It's a slightly less personal way of saying **you** when illustrating a point.

This sentence is correct. **One** is followed naturally by **oneself** in the sense that any person should look after himself/herself/themselves in these circumstances. It's a general statement of how a person should behave.

Your first sentence is quite different. It is no longer a general statement about best behaviour; instead it's an instruction in which **each one** refers back to unknown subjects who are commanded to look after themselves in these circumstances. An army commander might issue such an instruction to troops.

If all were male, you could phrase it as:

> Each one should look after himself in these circumstances:

If female:

> Each one should look after herself in these circumstances.

If uncertain, you can choose between:

> Each one should look after himself or herself in these circumstances

(which is rather long-winded), and

> Each one should look after themselves in these circumstances.

These days most people would opt for the latter.

But you can't say: Each one should look after oneself in these circumstances. It is not idiomatic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/one-and-one-s